# PSEXEC, access denied errors

Tags: access-denied, psexec, windows-scripting

While I'm using PSEXEC.exe getting 'Access denied' error for remote systems.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: I am also having this problem, but none of the solutions here or elsewhere have worked for me, as of 5/31/20.

Answer (score 89):

Hi i am placing here a summary from many sources online for various solutions to "access is denied" :
most information can be found here (including requirements needed) -  [sysinternal help](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic15919.html)

1. as someone mentioned add this reg key, and then restart the computer :

   > reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system
   > /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

   Read [this knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947232) to learn what this does and why it is
   needed
2. Disable firewall (note - this will leave you with out any firewall
   protection)

   > netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
3. if target user has a blank PW and you dont want to add one, run on target:

   > [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
   > "LimitBlankPasswordUse"=dword:00000000
4. This didnt work for me, but i have read it did for others in a few places,
   on target execute:

   > Start -> Run -> secpol.msc -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Network Access: Sharing > and security model for local accounts > Classic – local users authenticate as themselves

   if already in 'Classic':

   > move to "Guest only - .." run from elevated command prompt gpupdate \force
   > move back to 'Classic - .." again  run from elevated command prompt gpupdate \force
5. This one solved my issue:

   > run on target from elevated command prompt "net use" look at ouput chart and for shares listed in remote column there (i only deleted the disconnected ones - you can try them all)  run "net use [remote path from before list] /delete" then run 'net use \target\Admin$ /user:[user name]' enter prompt password request (if empty PW just press enter), viola should work.

Comment: 1) help me (also, semi-related, needed to fully qualify username with target server name since user was local to target server)

Comment: 4) worked for me when connect my windows 7 to a windows virtual pc XP Mode. Thanks!

Comment: Go to Files and Folders. -> View -> Scroll down to disable "Simple File Sharing" ON THE TARGET machine. That worked for me. I tried all the others first. including 5, which just reported Server not enabled for remote administration

Comment: The sysinternals help link which was http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic15919.html now reports "The Windows Sysinternals Forums have moved to TechNet Forums" and redirects in 10 sec, except not to the post, but to some generic list "category=sysinternals&sort=lastpostdesc". The "psexec could not start" post is now here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f02208a-feae-4914-9f2d-56c2d71484f9/psexec-could-not-start?forum=pstools and the first reply self-attributed to Karl contains the minimum requirements.

Comment: Also, the "FAQ" post has moved to here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8761bf03-8c05-493e-93b1-497f97ce9436/-faq-common-pstools-issues-?forum=pstools

Comment: I know this is old, but #1 did the trick for me on Windows 10,(Both machines)

Comment: @twobob: I could not find "simple file sharing" anywhere on the target computer, in settings or control panel.

Comment: @DavidSpector hmm yeah. I too can no longer find those settings in windows 10.
It used to be here https://helpdeskgeek.com/wp-content/pictures/2008/10/disablesimplefilesharing.png.webp  I suspect they renamed it to "Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)" which in my case if OFF.  They have shuffled the order a bit but that's still roughly in the same place give or take some fluff. Hope that's it for you buddy.

Answer (score 27):

I just solved an identical symptom, by creating the registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system\LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` and setting it to 1. [More details are available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction).

Comment: Yup, worked here. Thanks! To be extra clear, that must be a `REG_DWORD` key.

Comment: Thanks, I put his content in a .reg file and voila:    <br/>  `code` Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001`code`

Comment: Remember, when you make this change to this registry key a system reboot is necessary for the change to take affect

Comment: do you do this in the local or the target machine ? @WillBuffington

Comment: @AhmedCanUnbay in my case this was needed on the remote machine, and a reboot wasn't necessary (it fixed the problem immediately) -- both machines win11

Answer (score 15):

[This](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-access-denied-when-using-explicit-logon_topic17497.html) helped in my case:

```
cmdkey.exe /add:<targetname> /user:<username> /pass:<password>
psexec.exe \\<targetname> <remote_command>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, This work for me and it looks like the least complicated way to do it !!!

Comment: The reference link changed from http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-access-denied-when-using-explicit-logon_topic17497.html to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/efd64118-93c0-43ec-ba41-b2cd89ddfbd8/psexec-access-denied-when-using-explicit-logon?forum=pstools

Comment: Did not work for me. The 'access denied' problem doesn't seem to be the credentials.

Comment: FYI, that Technet link that @johnvkumpf provided no longer works. I get a page stating "The page you requested was removed"

Comment: Well, dang. Does not appear to be archived at archive.is nor archive.org.

Comment: In my case, this solved my issue.
Once I add credentials via "cmdkey" command, works like a charm. 
If i delete credentials via "cmdkey /delete" suddendly it stops working, even if I provide username and password to psexec in command line.
Quite strange...

Answer (score 11):

PsExec has whatever access rights its launcher has. It runs under regular Windows access control. This means whoever launched PsExec (be it either you, the scheduler, a service etc.) does not have sufficient rights on the target machine, or the target machine is not configured correctly. The first things to do are:

1. Make sure the launcher of PsExec is familiar to the target machine, either via the domain or by having the same user and password defined locally on both machines.
2. Use command line arguments to specify a user that is known to the target machine (-u user -p password)

If this did not solve your problem, make sure the target machine meets the minimum requirements, [specified here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f02208a-feae-4914-9f2d-56c2d71484f9/psexec-could-not-start?forum=pstools).

Comment: The "minimum requirements" post (reply) link which was http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=15919 now reports "The Windows Sysinternals Forums have moved to TechNet Forums" and redirects in 10 sec, except not to the post, but to some generic list "category=sysinternals&sort=lastpostdesc". The "psexec could not start" post is now here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f02208a-feae-4914-9f2d-56c2d71484f9/psexec-could-not-start?forum=pstools and the first reply self-attributed to Karl contains the minimum requirements.

Comment: Thanks, @johnvkumpf. Fixed the link according to your suggestion, glad you see it's still helpful 10 years after the original post. Feel free to suggest an edit to the answer next time (instead of commenting, you can actually fix the answer).

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like it was archived in archive.is nor archive.org.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the command

```
net use \\computername\ipc$ /user:adminname password
```

to get admin permissions on remote PC before use psexec.

Comment: When I run this command I get: "The command completed successfully." What's the purpose of running this command?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting this key on the target (remote) machine, and restart the machine:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001
```

See: http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic10924.html and http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2013/04/24/resolve-access-is-denied-using-psexec-with-a-local-admin-account/

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. And after a hard work, I found a easy and full solution:

1. I use **runas** to run the script in a admin account
2. I use the **-s parameter in psExec** to run in a system account
3. Inside the PsExec, I **login again** with a admin account
4. You can use **& to run multiples commands**
5. Remember to replace [USERNAME], [PASSWORD], [COMPUTERNAME], [COMMAND1] and [COMMAND2] with the real values

The code looks like this:

```
runas /user:[USERNAME] "psexec -e -h -s -u [USERNAME] -p [PASSWORD] \\[COMPUTERNAME] cmd /C [COMMAND1] & [COMMAND2]"
```

If you whant to debug your script in the another machine, run the following template:

```
runas /user:[USERNAME] "psexec -i -e -h -s -u [USERNAME] -p [PASSWORD] \\[COMPUTERNAME] cmd /C [COMMAND1] & [COMMAND2] & pause"
```

Comment: When I right-click my cmd file in Explorer and select Run as Administrator, I still get 'access denied'.

Answer (score 4):

I just added "-с" parameter. It makes Psexec copy executable to remote machine. So it works without access errors.

Comment: Okay, but it seems wasteful to keep copying system commands that are already there on the remote computer.

Answer (score 4):

I found Sophos kept placing psexec.exe into the Quarantine section.  Once I authorized it, it ran fine.

Answer (score 4):

I still use `psexec`, even on win 10. Replace the `psexec.exe` in the Windows 10's `win32` folder with the older version to work -> I use version 2.11.0.0. The Windows 10 version I was using would only run .bat files as background/hidden process on the remote computer. Took a whole day to figure this out.

Adding the registry key from above to the remote computer helps as well:

```
   reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\system /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: As a 2016 answer to a 2009 question, I'm not sure what more this adds since the registry key is already well documented in the previous answers.

Answer (score 3):

I had a case where AV was quarantining Psexec - had to disable On-access scanning

Answer (score 2):

I found another reason PSEXEC (and other PS tools) fail - If something (...say, a virus or trojan) hides the Windows folder and/or its files, then PSEXEC will fail with an "Access is Denied" error, PSLIST will give the error "Processor performance object not found on " and you'll be left in the dark as to the reason.

You can RDP in; You can access the admin$ share; You can view the drive contents remotely, etc. etc., but there's no indication that file(s) or folder(s) being hidden is the reason.

I'll be posting this information on several pages that i was perusing yesterday while trying to determine the cause of this odd problem, so you might see this elsewhere verbatim - just thought I'd put the word out before anyone else pulled their hair out by the roots trying to understand why the performance counter has anything to do with PSEXEC running.

Comment: You're giving what is perhaps good, accurate info, but on the wrong question.

Comment: I excluded my PSTOOLS directory from my antivirus program (Malwarebytes) and still got 'access denied'.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who may stumble upon this. There is a recent (Dec 2013) Security Update from Microsoft Windows on Windows 7 that is preventing remote execution. 
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2893294/en-us

I uninstalled the Security Update by going to Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features\Installed Updates

It worked right after that.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked, but only after I upgraded PSEXEC to 2.1 from Microsoft.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
>   "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy"=dword:00000001 See:
>   http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic10924.html

I had a slightly older version that didn't work.  I used it to do some USMT work via Dell kace, worked a treat :)

Comment: I have PSEXEC 2.2, but adding this key and value did not help.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows Server 2012 R2 I had trouble to run from user account

```
psexec -u administrator -p password \\machinename -h -s -d -accepteula cmd.exe
```

But it works fine if you run without parameters `-h -s`. That's why I use this to solve my trouble:

```
psexec -accepteula -u administrator -p password \\machinename %PathToLocalUtils%\psexec.exe -h -s -d  cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get access to remote machines unless I had *UAC* disabled.

That has to be done locally, either from control panel or running the following through cmd:

```
reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

While *UAC* is enabled, make sure you run *cmd* as **administrator**.

Comment: Erro I got : Microsoft Web Driver can't be used with the Built-In Administrator account or while User Account Control is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

For a different command I decided to change the network from public to work.
After trying to use the psexec command again it worked again.
So to get psexec to work try to change your network type from public to work or home.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of way but I could not use *psexec*. It gives "Access denied". After I change the target user account type from **Standard** to **Admin**, I connected the machine via psexec.

I researched the reason why admin type account is required then I found [this answer.](https://serverfault.com/questions/280482/how-to-use-psexec-without-admin-privileges-on-target-machine#answer-280756)

You can change target machine user account this way: Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change Account Type. You must enter an admin account and password to change that account if you logged in standard account.

After that I logged in with this command: `psexec \\remotepcname -u remoteusername -p remotepassword cmd`

Answer (score 0):

Tried all suggestions above, but still was unable to resolve the error. Finally once I made the below change, I could successfully run the PSexec command.

Turns out that when you have UAC enabled psexec does not work as supposed. We need to set `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA` to 0 then psexec starts working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of the issue

make sure your system execution policy is set

> RemoteSigned

verify it using  `get-ExecutionPolicy`

after that just run the command

[image]

`winrm qc` command and prompt `y`

thats it.