# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity throws PrincipalServerDownException

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices, account-management, userprincipal

I have an application that needs to bind against a remote customer's Active Directory to perform authentication tasks.

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "customer.org", "ou=people,dc=customer,dc=org", ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind, "bindaccount@customer.org", "password"))
{
   var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username); // after several seconds, throws PrincipalServerDownException

   if (user == null) return null; // user doesn't exist

   // check if the account is locked out, etc. (omitted)   

   // quickly validate credentials
   if (!ctx.ValidateCredentials(username, password, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind)) return null; // bad credentials

   return user;   
}
```

The exception is:

> PrincipalServerDownException: The server is not operational.

```
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetAsPrincipal(Object storeObject, Object discriminant)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRefHelper(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate, Boolean useSidHistory)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRef(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
```

Until today, things were working fine. One change is that the application running this code was upgraded from 4 to 4.5. I can't say for sure if the problem occurred immediately after the upgrade, or it's just a coincidence.

I'd been using AdFind to test binding against the customer's AD, and it seems to be working fine.

Another interesting thing is that the `PrincipalContext` initializes just fine (and thus validates its connection against the remote store), and if I comment out the `FindByIdentity` call so just `ctx.ValidateCredentials` is called, that works fine, too.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608971/net-4-5-bug-in-userprincipal-findbyidentity-system-directoryservices-accountma?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually 4.5 might well be the Problem.  There have been some changes to "secure" UerPrincipal.FindByIdentity. They tend to break code in cross Domain and workroup => Domain Scenarios.

You have at least two possibilities:

- Revert to 4.0
- Use DirectoryEntry instead

Comment: Yeah, I investigated it further as per @Josh E's comment above. When using `FindByIdentity` it seems to try to resolve site services using DNS, which is not gonna work. I tried faking the DNS zones and records it asks for but no joy. I have reverted back to `DirectoryEntry`, much to my chagrin.