# C# .NET FindByIdentity fails when using ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm having trouble obtaining a user from an Active Directory server when using SSL. The following code block works fine up unti the `FindByIdentity` call when it is throwing a `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException - An operations error occurred` exception.

```
options = ContextOptions.SimpleBind | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer;
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mycompany.org:636", null, options))
{
    if (!context.ValidateCredentials(name, password, options))
    {
        LdapStatus = 0;
        return null;
    }

    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, name);

    ... other stuff to find groups ...
}
```

Interestingly, if I use `options = ContextOptions.SimpleBind` without the SSL flag or if go to port `:389` together with the options `options = ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.Signing | ContextOptions.Sealing` it works just fine. So I guess it has something to do with `FindByIdentity` not working with SSL? But I have seen examples (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173184/userprincipal-findbyidentity-throws-principalserverdownexception)) that this should indeed work.

Anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Btw. I'm running on .NET 4.8

Comment: The answer in the StackOverflow link says the `.Net` version is the problem. Have you tried to revert it to a previous version, like `.Net 4` as suggested ?

Comment: Well, I'm not running cross-domain, I get a different exception and it's been 10 years and several .NET updates...but I guess I can try it when I get the chacne

Comment: Do you know if the SSL certificate being used on the server is valid and trusted (not self-signed) and matches exactly the domain name you're using to connect (not issued to the specific domain controller)?

Comment: I'm fairly confident that its valid since it's only the `FindByIdentity` part that's not working. I can validate the credentials just fine.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/ldap-over-ssl-connection-issues

Comment: you can either add the server's SSL certificate to the client's trusted certificate store or disable SSL verification by setting ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback to delegate { return true; }. However, this is not recommended as it can compromise the security of the connection.