# PsExec Windows 8 access denied

Tags: windows-8, psexec

I've 8 computers running Windows 8 (the basic edition) and I'm trying to run some application on each of them with a batch script.

I tried:

```
PsExec.exe -i -d -u USER -p PASSWD \\PCNAME explorer.exe
```

But it gives me:

```
PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access GATE1:
Access is denied.
```

It works fine on other PCs with Windows 7 Professional.

Does it works just on Pro edition? If so, is there a way I can run something remotely on Win 8?

Comment: Probably more a question for superuser.com. Also look at the side bar, there are similar topics, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828432/psexec-access-denied-errors

Comment: I solved it, setting a registry key "EnableLUA" to 0.

Answer (score 14):

I resolved the same PsExec "Access is Denied" error on a Windows 8 Pro 64-bit target machine with the following registry modification on the target machine:

Registry Location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Add DWORD LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy

Set LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to 1

(Reboot)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me from Win 8 pro to VMware Win 8.1 Pro Preview. I needed to also "sc start RemoteRegistry" on target machine to avoid "Cannot connect to remote registry on ..."

Answer (score 0):

In domain based environment, Microsoft PowerShell Remoting may be an alternative to PsExec.
In workgroup setup, especially among many different versions of Windows it may get bit challenging.

PowerShell remoting requires PowerShell 2.0 on both client and server.

Also, ssh with it's all capabilities (including launching remote commands) works under Windows, even free servers (freesshd) and clients (PuTTY family) are available . Downside is requirement for highly privileged account (usually, in some Administrators group) - at least for initial setup.

The GATE1 part in your log is interesting - PsExec requires so called "admin share" enabled (not sure does it work in Windows 8). I'd bet it's not the system, but a network issue.