# PsExec: Couldn't access [MachineName]: Access is Denied

Tags: cmd, remote-access, psexec

I'm trying to use PsExec to start a process on a remote machine. I've looked at a few other questions here and tried what they've suggested to no avail, which leads me to believe I may be overlooking something that wasn't mentioned in those questions or is taken for granted.

[Here is one of the questions I've looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828432/psexec-access-denied-errors), as well as a couple of [forum posts](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-access-is-denied_topic547.html). The second link is the one I'm interested in. One of the posters suggests using net use to see if the credentials I'm trying to use with PsExec work for that, and they do. When I try to run PsExec, I'm running it from an administrator instance of cmd, and I use this command:

```
PsExec.exe \\[MachineName] -i -u [domain]\[user] -p [password] calc.exe
```

This is unsuccessful, and returns:

```
Couldn't Access [MachineName]:
Access is denied.
```

However, when I issued this command in the same instance of cmd:

```
net use \\[MachineName] /user:[domain]\[user]
```

I was prompted for a password, to which I entered `[password]`, and it returned:

```
The command completed successfully.
```

This seems like all the relevant information to me, and it also seemed that way in the other posts I looked at, but I'm not sure what else to add. I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out, with no success. I'd appreciate any help, and let me know if you need any other information from me.