# Does PsExec work on Windows 10 ? (Command Prompt)

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, remote-access, remote-desktop, psexec

I'm trying to remotely access to my computer on LAN with CMD by using PsTools. The remote computer uses Windows 10

I tried a lot of things in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828432/psexec-access-denied-errors). I'm still stuck with "Access Denied".

Does somebody knows if it works on Windows 10 Professional ? If yes, is there something special to do before ?

Answer (score 1):

It does work. Check your windows build version. PsExec (tools too I presume) DOES NOT work on the new version 1903, though there is speculation it has stopped working for build versions from 1809. Though I need to mention I am troubleshooting myself now establishing connection to PsExec service since I upgraded to 1903 and reverted back to 1511 (without having to refresh or reinstall windows)